# Regular expression replace only one matching

Tags: javascript, regex, xml-namespaces

I have a regular expression code in JavaScript

```
const regexns = /[A-Za-z]\:[A-Za-z]/gi;
data = data.replace(regexns, '__NS__');
```

If I apply on this XML

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="com.zigma.Controller">
```

I get

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmln__NS__x="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    f__NS__ontroller="com.zigma.Controller">
```

which means I loose 1 letter next and previous to `:`

How to replace the `:` without loosing those side letters, 
is there any option in regular expression itself or we need to do loops and conditions and split like that?

Expected output is

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns__NS__fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx__NS__controller="com.zigma.Controller">
```

Comment: What do you want instead? `__NS__controller="com....`? Or do you want to keep the leading `f` somewhere too?

Comment: I am not getting `__NS__controller` II am only getting `__NS__ontroller` the `c` is cut , same happening the left hand side

Comment: What exactly is the desired output? `__NS__controller="com....`? `fx:__NS__controller="com....`? `__NS__fx:controller="com....`?

Comment: I want `xmlns__NS__fx` and `fx__NS__controller` for the two namespace prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the letter before the `:` so it can be added into the replacement, and lookahead for the letter after the `:` so it doesn't get matched. Also note that since you're using the case-insensitive flag, there's no need to repeat `[A-Za-z]`, and colons do not need to be escaped:

```js
const data = `<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="com.zigma.Controller">
    `;
console.log(data.replace(/([a-z]):(?=[a-z])/gi, '$1__NS__'));
```

Depending on the shape of your input, you may be able to use word boundaries instead:

```js
const data = `<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="com.zigma.Controller">
    `;
console.log(data.replace(/\b:\b/gi, '__NS__'));
```

For something even more robust I'd recommend parsing the string into an XML document, and then iterating through the elements of the document, replacing attributes which contain the `:` pattern with the new attribute.

Comment: thanks, but I am currently into generic lexical `compiler design` for an `erroneous` arbitrary string, I definitely have experience in what you said about XML parsing